# Using case_when inside mutate across

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, tidyverse

I have survey data such as this. The only responses are "NA" or "Yes".

```
    data_in <-read_table2("ID   Q26_1_1 Q26_1_2 Q26_1_3 Q26_1_4
1   NA  NA  NA  Yes
2   NA  NA  NA  NA
3   Yes Yes Yes NA
4   NA  Yes Yes NA
5   NA  NA  NA  NA
")
```

I have to apply the following logic to the data:

1. If **Q26_1_4** == "Yes", then Q26_1_1, Q26_1_2, Q26_1_3, should be
   "No".
2. If any of the **three variables** Q26_1_1,Q26_1_2,Q26_1_3 are "Yes",
   then **all the other 26_1 series of fields** (Q26_1_1, Q26_1_2, Q26_1_3,
   Q26_1_4) should be "No" (of course, excluding the field(s) that has the "Yes" in it).
3. If the entire series is NA, leave it as NA.

I was able to execute the 1st and the 3rd logic, but I am struggling to execute the 2nd logic:

- If any of the **three variables** Q26_1_1,Q26_1_2,Q26_1_3 are "Yes",
  then **all the other 26_1 series of fields** (Q26_1_1, Q26_1_2, Q26_1_3,
  Q26_1_4) should be "No" (of course, excluding the field(s) that has the "Yes" in it). The difficulty arises in attempting to keep these "Yes" fields as they are, while mutating the other fields to a "No".

This is where I am so far:

```
  attempt <- data_in %>% mutate(across(matches("^Q26_1_1$|Q26_1_2$|Q26_1_3$"),.fns=~case_when(Q26_1_4=="Yes"~"No",
                                                                                    TRUE~as.character(.))))
```

This is what I want my data to look like:

```
data_out <- read_table2("ID Q26_1_1 Q26_1_2 Q26_1_3 Q26_1_4
1   No  No  No  Yes
2   NA  NA  NA  NA
3   Yes Yes Yes No
4   No  Yes Yes No
5   NA  NA  NA  NA
")
```

Any suggestions are **greatly appreciated**! I think I might have to use a loop, but I can't figure out how. If I converted to numeric and summed all 4 columns, I could use something like..?

```
  for (i in data_in){
    if (is.na(i) & data_in[5]>0) {
      i=="No"
    }
  }
```

Comment: *"three variables Q26_1_2:Q26_1_3"* ... there are only two there ...?

Comment: Another note, you've got exact column names so you don't need `matches` and regex. Simpler to use `across(all_of("Q26_1_1", "Q26_1_2", "Q26_1_3"))`. If you want to use regex, you could actually use a pattern like `matches("^Q26_1_[1-3]$")` which would match those 3 columns.

Comment: @akrun any chance you might be able to help with this...

Comment: @GregorThomas how would I match any digit following Q26_1_. I thought this should capture any digit, but it does not...  matches(("^Q26_1_[:digit:]")))

Comment: In R you need to double the `[` for the POSIX regex patterns like that. Either use `[[:digit:]]` or `[0-9]`.

Comment: @GregorThomas thank you ! one more thing,  I am trying to select all the digits except for 5 or 7. matches("^Q43_[[:digit:]]^5/7") isn't doing it, even though I thought ^ meant "except for".

Comment: `[1234689]` or `[1-4689]`. `^` means "not", but it doesn't do a set difference like that. `[^57]` would be any character except for 5 or 7 (which won't work for you here, because you want to restrict to numbers, where as `[^57]` will happily match non-numbers). I highly recommend [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) for trying out regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with a helper column. (You can, of course, `... select(-any_yes)` at the end to clean up.)

```
data_in %>%
  mutate(
    # Logic 1
    across(matches("^Q26_1_[1-3]$"),
      ~case_when(Q26_1_4 == "Yes" ~ "No", TRUE ~ .)
    ),
    # Logic 2
    any_yes = rowSums(select(., matches("^Q26_1_[1-3]$")) == "Yes", na.rm = TRUE) >= 1,
    across(matches("^Q26_1_[0-9]$"),
      ~ case_when(
        any_yes ~ coalesce(., "No"), # logic 2
        TRUE ~ .                     # logic 3
      )     
    ))
# # A tibble: 5 x 6
#      ID Q26_1_1 Q26_1_2 Q26_1_3 Q26_1_4 any_yes
#   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <lgl>  
# 1     1 No      No      No      Yes     FALSE  
# 2     2 NA      NA      NA      NA      FALSE  
# 3     3 Yes     Yes     Yes     No      TRUE   
# 4     4 No      Yes     Yes     No      TRUE   
# 5     5 NA      NA      NA      NA      FALSE
```